# SwiftUI: fit SF Icon into line height

Tags: image, text, swiftui, icons, line-height

When I try to display an icon next to a text, the Image adds unwanted space above, increasing the line height and I don't understand how I can control it. I tried frame, padding, resizable without success. I also tried the Label element, which my XCode does not recognize ("unresolved identifier Label").

[image: Image adds unwanted space around it, increasing the line height]

The image shows the difference between an Image and Text, where the Image adds unwanted space.

Where is that extra space coming from and how can I control it?

```
VStack {
    Text("User Name").bold()
    HStack {
        Text("hello@contact.com")
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
        .font(.system(size: 14))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The image shows the difference between an Image and Text, where the Image adds unwanted space.
> Where is that extra space coming from and how can I control it?

It is all about default spacing... it is, yes, *strange*, use explicit, eg

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
   // ... other your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! So weird that the same isn't happening with Text, kinda difficult to understand how SwiftUI is working behind the scenes.